# Counting the number of times a given ID has a specific value, and then using an arithmetic operator

Tags: sql, hive

Running a query in Hive using Apache, and I want to count the number of times a given ID has an order number, and then only include ID's which have at least 3 orders. I used something like this to aggregate the values:

```
    select customer_id, count (distinct order_id) 
    from customer_table
    group by customer_id
```

What's a good way of pulling only customer_id's that have more than 3 orders? I tried adding a where clause with an arithmetic operator can't get it to work (e.g. `where count (distinct claim_id) is >= 3`)

Comment: Do you need `count(distinct)`?  `count(*)` is usually faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` clause:

```
select customer_id, count(distinct order_id) 
from customer_table
group by customer_id
having count(distinct order_id) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a group by and distinct in the same query.
Please see open hive Jira [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16648)

I have tested the below script in hive and it works for me.

```
select customer_id, order_id, count(1) as counting from customer_table
group by customer_id, order_id
having counting >= 3
```